# Error in terminal when installing pods for Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal, cocoapods

Im trying to install a pods on my Xcode project.
Here is my pod File:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'aa' do
    pod 'Canvas'
end
```

I get these errors in terminal when trying to install pods 
[The errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7lO2.png)

Thank you!

---

Edit: 
Nevermind I got it to work and installed it
I added this in my Podfile.  (cc is another project). 
project '/Users/ashotgharibyan/Desktop/cc/cc.xcodeproj'

but now Im having  [this warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr1rJ.png).
Any Help? Is there a way to fix it, or I shouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple as Said by Xcode you forgot to write `[super awakeFromNib]` method in `-(void)awakeFromNib` method.

So, your method should be

```
-(void)swakeFromNib{
[super awakeFromNib]
//Now write Your Stuff here
}
```

You can check more detail on this link [awakeFromNib](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1402907-awakefromnib?language=objc)

> you must call the super implementation of awakeFromNib to give parent
>   classes the opportunity to perform any additional initialization they
>   require. Although the default implementation of this method does
>   nothing, many UIKit classes provide non-empty implementations. You may
>   call the super implementation at any point during your own
>   awakeFromNib method.